# invoke formula as cell changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need to run formula when length of target cell changes. My formula works when I exit my target cell. But I want to have my formula run every time I type into the target cell.

I am using Excel to help me memorize some spoken lines for a video "head shot". I put the verbiage in cell A1 and hide it. I then type what I am trying to memorize in cell B1. What I want to do is compare what I type in cell B1 to the left portion of A1 AS I TYPE IT. If it matches I continue. If not, I show the partial contents of a1 in c1. The code below for the C1 cell formula works once I exit cell B1. 
What I want is to run the formula as I type in B1, not just when I exit.

I am running Excel 2016 under windows 10 in a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop.

[in cell c1]

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,LEN(B1))=B1,"",LEFT(A1,LEN(B1)))
```

[as VBA]

```
Option Explicit  
    Do While Len(a1) > Len(b1)
    If (Left(a1, Len(b1)) <> b1) Then c1 = Left(a1, Len(b1))
    Loop
```

Actual results is that I get the comparison only when I exit B1. I want the A1 : B1 comparison to take place every time I type a letter into cell B1

Comment: The only way to get a real-time update as you're typing is to use a textbox control that has a Change event.  If you're just typing into a cell, there's no way to get a real time update like you've described.  The update wouldn't happen until the cell update is completed and you've exited the cell (which is the current, and expected, behavior).

Comment: ^ that. Cells don't fire any events while in edit mode.

Comment: ok. understand.